# Using Strings with submenu's to print reports

Tags: java, arrays, string, report, text-files

I need some help finishing up my program. I have it set up so that it lists 6 options. Options 2 and 3 are supposed to open their own lists of 4 options. Right now when I select 2 or 3 it opens the correct options they should, but if I try and select one of their subsequent reports it just kicks me back to the main menu. My questions is that is their a way to alter my code to make this work the way I want it too, or should I use command-line and either way I could use some help with it as I'm thoroughly stumped. Any help is much appreciated.

> Error Message: doctorMain (String[]) in Patient_Reports cannot be
>   applied to ()
>
> Error Message is located in my main method
>
> Compiler Error Message: Error:(30, 24) java: method doctorMain in
>   class   Test.Patient_Reports cannot be applied to given types;
>   required: java.lang.String[]     found: no arguments     reason:
>   actual and formal argument lists differ in length

```
Data File (patient.txt):  
    11111,Smith,Norris,Thyroid,1000.00
    11112,Obama,Norris,Lasek,500.00
    11113,Hoover,Norris,Dental,100.00
    11114,Cena,Norris,Lasek,500.00
    11115,Leto,Norris,Thyroid,1000.00
    22221,Clark,Bond,Thyroid,1000.00
    22222,Chang,Bond,Lasek,500.00
    22223,Dent,Bond,Dental,100.00
    22224,Nixon,Bond,Lasek,500.00
    22225,Washington,Bond,Dental,100.00
    33331,Jones,Lee,Dental,100.00
    33332,Ross,Lee,Lasek,500.00
    33333,Gates,Lee,Thyroid,1000.00
    33334,Johnson,Lee,Thyroid,1000.00
    33335,Carter,Lee,Dental,100.00
```

Condensed version of the Program
Program: (class is Patient_Reports)

```
    package Test;

    /**
    * Created by Brandon on 9/6/2015.
    */
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;
    public class Patient_Reports {

    private final int[] id = new int[100];
    private final String[] patient = new String[100];
    private final String[] doctor = new String[100];
    private final String[] surgery = new String[100];
    private final double[] cost = new double[100];
    private int count = -1;
    private int i;

    //Main Method
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int selection;
        String report_number;
        Patient_Reports patient = new Patient_Reports();
        patient.start_system();
        report_number = patient.menu();
        selection = Integer.parseInt(report_number);
        while (selection != 2) {
            if (selection == 1) {
                patient.surgeryDoctorMenu();
                patient.doctorMain();  <<<<<<<<<< error message is here        
            }
            report_number = patient.menu();
            selection = Integer.parseInt(report_number);
        }//While Loop
        patient.writeReports();
        System.exit(0);
    }//End Main

    //Read Data File into Array
    private void start_system() {
        String newLine;
        try {
            //Read text file into an array.
            BufferedReader Patient_Reports = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("patient.txt"));
            while ((newLine = Patient_Reports.readLine()) != null) {
                //Comma Delimited
                StringTokenizer delimiter = new StringTokenizer(newLine, ",");
                count = count + 1;
                id[count] = Integer.parseInt(delimiter.nextToken());
                patient[count] = delimiter.nextToken();
                doctor[count] = delimiter.nextToken();
                surgery[count] = delimiter.nextToken();
                cost[count] = Double.parseDouble(delimiter.nextToken());
            }//While Loop
            Patient_Reports.close();
        }//End Try
        catch (IOException error) {
            //Error in File Writing
            System.out.println("Error on file read " + error);
        }//End Catch
    }//End start_system

    //Report Menu
    private String menu() {
        String report;
        String Output = "Reports:" + "\n" + "1. Surgeries Doctor Report" + "\n" +
                "2. Exit" + "\n" +
                " " + "\n" +
                "Select a Report >";
        report = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                Output, "", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
        return report;
    }//End Menu

    //Store Data File in Array
    private void writeReports() {
        try {
            BufferedWriter Patient_Reports = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("patient_out.txt"));
            for (i = 0; i <= count; ++i) {
                //Comma Delimit
                Patient_Reports.write(id[i] + "," + patient[i] + "," + doctor[i] + "," +
                        surgery[i] + "," + cost[i] + ",");
                //Write a new line in patient_out.txt
                Patient_Reports.newLine();
            }//End For Loop
            Patient_Reports.close();
        }//End Try
        catch (IOException error) {
            //Error on Write to File
            System.out.println("Error on file write " + error);
        }//End Error
    }//End writeReports

    //Main for Doctor Reports
    public static void doctorMain (String[] args) {
        int doctor_selection;
        String doctor_name;
        Patient_Reports doctor = new Patient_Reports();
        doctor.start_system();
        doctor_name = doctor.surgeryDoctorMenu();
        doctor_selection = Integer.parseInt(doctor_name);
        while (doctor_selection !=2) {
            if (doctor_selection == 1) {
                doctor.norrisSurgeries();
            } 
            doctor_name = doctor.surgeryDoctorMenu();
            doctor_selection = Integer.parseInt(doctor_name);
        }//While Loop
    }//End doctorMain

    //Report on all surgeries of a specific doctor (prompt for the doctor)
    //Report Menu
    private String surgeryDoctorMenu() {
        System.out.println("Surgeries Doctor Report:");
        String doctor_report;
        String Output = "Surgery Doctor Reports:" + "\n" + "1. Norris Surgeries Report" + "\n" +
                "2. Bond Surgeries Report" + "\n" +
                "3. Lee Surgeries Report" + "\n" +
                "4. Exit" + "\n" +
                " " + "\n" +
                "Select a Report >";
        doctor_report = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                Output, "", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
        return doctor_report;
    }//end menu\

    //Report on all surgeries by Dr. Norris
    private void norrisSurgeries() {
        System.out.println("Norris Surgeries Report:");
        System.out.println("5" + " ");
    }//End norrisSurgeries
}
```

Comment: Please create [complete but minimal example which will let us reproduce your problem](http://sscce.org/). it will be easier for us to help you and you will find our answers easier. There is also a chance that you will solve your own problem while creating such example, so it is worth spending some time on it.

Comment: I'm honestly not sure what you are expecting, when you press [2], to calls `patient.surgeryDoctorMenu();` which displays a menu and returns the option that the user selected, but you do nothing with it and the same things happens when you press [3]

Comment: I condenced the code to show the issue better. Maybe I just don't know how to do it, but I want the sublevel to display my reports. In the condenced version for example, if you run it. I want to be able to select Surgeries Doctor Report, then select Norris Surgeries Report and have it display the report.